# Inheritance of class arguments

Tags: javascript, class

I would like to make Bob a `NPC` with all `NPC` class parameters, and all `Civil` class parameters, **but** I don't know how to declare it so both Classes read the `params` associative array to define Bob properties.

My code:

```js
class Civil {
  constructor(params) {
    params["gold"] ? this.gold = params["gold"] : this.gold = 0;
  }
}

class NPC extends Civil {
  constructor(params) {
    super();
    params["name"] ? this.name = params["name"] : this.name = "No name defined";
    params["race"] ? this.race = params["race"] : this.race = "No race defined";
  }
}

var bob = new NPC({
  "name": "Bob",
  "race": "Human",
  "gold": 10
});

console.log(bob.name);
//returns that "params" is undefined in Civil class
```

If I don't use `params` in the `Civil` class and simply set this.gold to an int, everything works, and Bob.gold returns the int, Bob.name returns "Bob", and Bob.race returns "Human".

It's one of the first time I experiment with classes (to make a small game), and I don't fully understand how class inheritance works.

Comment: `super();` - you aren't passing in anything, hence why the super constructor reports there are no `params`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `params` to `super()`. Otherwise the class `Civil` is initiated without any parameters, and doesn't have access to those passed to `NPC`. Also, you can make the assignment of `this` variables a little shorter.

```js
class Civil {
  constructor(params) {
    if(!params) throw new Error("Params must be set")
    this.gold = params["gold"] ? params["gold"] : 0;
  }
}

class NPC extends Civil {
  constructor(params) {
    if(!params) throw new Error("Params must be set")
    super(params); // <-- pass them here.
    this.name = params["name"] ? params["name"] : "No name defined";
    this.race = params["race"] ? params["race"] : "No race defined";
  }
}

var bob = new NPC({
  "name": "Bob",
  "race": "Human",
  "gold": 10
});

console.log(bob.name);
//returns that "params" is undefined in Civil class
```

Comment: @J.Allain U can also set default params in the parent `constructor(params = {name: 'No name', race: 'No Race', gold: 'no gold'})`, the nice thing is that you will directly notice when you call the class with no params.

Answer (score 0):

Also, based on [Luca Kiebel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52354479/912046) (missing params in `super` call) and [Michelangelo's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52354456/inheritance-of-class-arguments/52354513#comment91653861_52354479) (use default arguments in constructor), I would rewrite like this:

```js
class Civil {
  constructor(params = { "gold": 0 }) {
    this.gold = params["gold"];
  }
}

class NPC extends Civil {
  constructor(params = { name: "No name", race: "No race" } ) {
    super(params);
    this.name = params["name"];
    this.race = params["race"];
  }
}

var bob = new NPC({
  "name": "Bob",
  "race": "Human",
  "gold": 10
});
console.log("Name (NPC with custom params): " + bob.name); // Ok

bob = new NPC();
console.log("Name (NPC with default params): " + bob.name); // Ok, no error
```

You may get an error if you do not check for params existence / validity:

> "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'gold' of
>   undefined"

```js
class Civil {
  constructor(params) {
    this.gold = params["gold"] ? params["gold"] : 0; // <-- missing check "params" exists
  }
}

class NPC extends Civil {
  constructor(params) {
    super(params);
    this.name = params["name"] ? params["name"] : "No name defined";
    this.race = params["race"] ? params["race"] : "No race defined";
  }
}

var bob = new NPC({
  "name": "Bob",
  "race": "Human",
  "gold": 10
});
console.log("Name (NPC with custom params): " + bob.name); // Ok

bob = new NPC();
console.log("Name (NPC with default params): " + bob.name); // Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'gold' of undefined
                                   // in NDC constructor
```

Comment: You don't actually have to check whether `params` is truthy every time, you can do that just once.

Comment: better to do multiple times than none ;)

Comment: So when is best to check it so I don't have to do it every line ?

Comment: You can either use what  Michelangelo suggested, check it once in an if/else, or, like I did, throw an error if they are not set, depending on what you prefer / how verbose it should be.

Comment: See @Michelangelo comment : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52354456/inheritance-of-class-arguments/52354513?noredirect=1#comment91653861_52354479 : define a default non null array in constructor arguments `constructor(params = {}) { ...}` or with default values set: `constructor(params = { "name": "No name", "race": "No race"}) { ...}`

Comment: Completed answer with default `params`.

Comment: @J.Allain depending on your strategy, you can either choose to use default values, OR to throw an exception when no params are passed, which exception would be handled by client code

Comment: The `(params = {})` is perfect for my use, thanks a lot !